# My Delete query isn't working properly

Tags: php, mysql

I'm in a bit of a trouble here. My delete query is not properly working.
The thing is i am deleting from 4 tables using inner join. the data is deleted in two tables but not in the rest two.

The thing is the post table contains more than one records and I have to delete all of them.But its deleting only the first one. And the fields_data table depends on posts tables. So if I'm able to delete all records from posts table, the problem will be solved also in the fields_data table.

Summarizing all I wanna do is to delete all the data from four tables("Workspace_name","Posts","Fields","Fields_data") according to following query. I hope it will make sense to you. Code is written below.

Thanks for your time. And on more thing its printing the success message(`Workspaces have been deleted`) as many times as the number of records in the posts table.But apparently its not deleting except the first one..

```
<?php

include "connection.php";

$sel="SELECT * FROM `posts` WHERE `workspace_id`='$workspace_id'";
$qus=mysqli_query($con,$sel);
$counter=mysqli_num_rows($qus);
if($qus){
    $pids=array();
    while($res=mysqli_fetch_assoc($qus)){
        $res['post_id'];
        $pids[]=$res['post_id'];
    }
}
else{
    echo mysqli_error($con);
}

for($i=0;$i<$counter;$i++){
    $dew="DELETE wn,f,p,fd
          FROM `workspace_name` AS wn
          INNER JOIN `fields` AS f 
          INNER JOIN `posts` AS p
          INNER JOIN `fields_data` AS fd
              ON wn.workspace_id=f.workspace_id AND p.post_id=fd.post_id
          WHERE wn.workspace_id='$workspace_id' AND p.post_id='$pids[$i]'";
    $quer=mysqli_query($con,$dew);
    if($quer){
        echo "Workspace and its corresponding fields have been deleted.. ";
    }
    else{
        echo mysqli_error($con);
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: Referential integrity preventing delete on other tables? or perhaps an improper order of delete?

Comment: You're missing `ON` clauses for some of the `JOIN` clauses.

Comment: You're joining `workspace_name` with `fields`, and joining `posts` with `fields_data`. But there's no join condition relating the first two tables with the last two tables.

Comment: @xQbert If it was violating a constraint, I think he would get an error and nothing would be deleted.

Comment: Could you make a sqlfiddle with sample data, and explain which rows should be deleted?

Comment: @Barmar...then how come it works when its not in the loop???
and is it necessary to have join condition joining the first two and the last two?? earlier i wrote thi wn.workspace_id=p.workspace_id....but then i thought its of no use so i removed this condition

Answer (score 1):

You are missing `ON` conditions on 2 tables `field` and `posts`

```
$dew="DELETE wn,f,p,fd
          FROM `workspace_name` AS wn
          INNER JOIN `fields` AS f _ON(wn.some_id = f.some_id)_
          INNER JOIN `posts` AS p  _ON(wn.some_id = c.some_id)_
          INNER JOIN `fields_data` AS fd
              ON wn.workspace_id=f.workspace_id AND p.post_id=fd.post_id
          WHERE wn.workspace_id='$workspace_id' AND p.post_id='$pids[$i]'";
```

Comment: This is not correct because of the where criteria only 1 post will be removed.

Comment: @shadow he has applied conditions on 2 tables in `where` so there is possibility that all these 3 tables are matched using this condition

Comment: nope, see the select query at the beginning of the code in the question.

Comment: yes I can see that he is fetching data from 1 table and then he is joining that able with multiple to delete rows from that table + another 2 tables

Answer (score 0):

You need to properly join the 4 tables in the delete query and do not use a loop. In the first loop the workspace will be removed with a post, but in the 2nd iteration there is no workspace left, so the inner join will not yield any records from the posts table either.

```
DELETE wn,f,p,fd FROM `workspace_name` AS wn INNER JOIN `fields` AS f
ON wn.workspace_id=f.workspace_id INNER JOIN `posts` AS p
ON wn.workspace_id=p.workspace_id INNER JOIN `fields_data` AS fd
ON p.post_id=fd.post_id 
WHERE wn.workspace_id='$workspace_id'
```

Comment: you are 100% right.. but how am i supposed to delete multiple rows of posts and fields_data without a loop??

Comment: Your above query will delete all the corresponding posts of workspaces...but how to delete the records from field_data because there is no workspace_id column in that table...should i add one or there is another way??

Comment: Based on your delete query the fields_data table is joined with the posts table on post_id field, so I do not get your question! Turn my above query into a select and if it selects the right records from the tables, then the delete will delete the right records.